# Fail the add dependency in pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I try to add a dependency in maven pom. But Following  error is occurred.

> Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.myproject:myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.company:DEFENDANCY_X_X:jar:1.100.100.123: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for com.company:DEFENDANCY_X_X:jar:1.100.100.123: Failure
>   to find com.company:DEFENDANC_PARENT:pom:${DEFENDANC_PARENT-Version}
>   in https://xxx.vvvv.com/artifactory/internal/ was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of mdc.local has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]"

I added dependency is child project. that child project is used the property value that is configured in parent pom. I add dependency is DEFENDANCY_X_X:jar:1.100.100.123. And DEFENDANC_PARENT is the DEFENDANCY_X_X's  parent project

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>DEFENDANCY_X_X</artifactId>
    <version>1.100.100.123</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: you should share your pom instead of trying to explain config in statements.

Comment: i added my pom into the question

Comment: Based on the error message `${DEFENDANC_PARENT-Version}` the pom you have given is not the one you have used for building..Please show the full pom file etc. otherwise it's impossible to help...